# Translation/Commentary on Targum

Tags: product-recommendation, midrash, targumin

I'm looking for a translation or commentary on Targum Onkelos, especially for the non-literal parts (such as on *Birkas Yaakov* and *Shiras Hayam*).

It can be in either Hebrew or English.

Comment: I've seen newer Chumashim with the explanation of R' Nosson Adler [of England] which explains part of Onkelus. Another help may be to use a Mikraot Gedolot which usually has the Targum Yerushalmi & Yonathan - and include a Peirush Yerushalmi/Yonathan under them for the harder words. but they don't always match Onkelus - especially in _esoteric_  parts like the Shira. [NOT an answer, as it's too superficial.]

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53433/759

Comment: Answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/105949/11501

Answer (score 3):

There is a five-volume translation of *Targum Onkelos* recently published by Gefen, which can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9652295213).

[This website](http://targum.info/targumic-texts/pentateuchal-targumim/) also contains a (seemingly) complete translation of the *targum*, albeit an older translation.

Comment: The first linked set is excellent, especially if you're looking for cross references for the _midrashim_ alluded to in _targum_.

Comment: @WAF tread carefully. the author has been known (in other works of his) to grossly misrepresent or misunderstand Torah sources. I worry that this translation might have mistakes and/or problems, though I haven't looked at this particular work of his myself

Comment: @Matt Like what? Good to know.

Comment: @WAF I haven't read the translation so I don't know if there's anything wrong with it, but I've seen (what I think are) gross misreadings of sources in his books on the rambam. If you look at some of the articles on his blog it isn't hard to find some crazy (and wrong) things over there. [here's one example](http://booksnthoughts.com/why-women-must-start-shabbat-before-men/) but there are many more

Answer (score 3):

there's a fantastic 5 volume set in hebrew called מעט צרי 'written by a talmid chochom who learns in the Mir in yerushalayim. It has haskomos from Dayan Fisher zt"l & yblcht"v Rav Nissin Karelitz shlit"a 
the author's number in israel is 02-537-3188