# Looking for an english translation of targum onkeles

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, translation, english, targumin

I am looking for an english orthodox translation of targum onkeles or, if a translation doesn't exist, maybe a shiur which goes through targum in english on a weekly basis.

Comment: check sefaria...

Comment: @sam - As far as I can see, [Sefaria only has a few passukim in Bereishis](https://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Genesis.1?lang=bi_) translated to English. So no use there.

Comment: I'm curious why you want a translation of Onkeles, which is a translation of the Torah to Aramaic.

Comment: Oliver's link to the first answer sums it up pretty well why I would want an english translation. Also onkelos is a tannaic source so his commentary carries a lot more weight than later commentaries  and to be fair most later commentaries assume that we know onkelos when they give a different explanation and also to simply  improve my aramaic vocabulary.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53178/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I found:

[https://www.amazon.com/Onkelos-Torah-Understanding-Bible-Text/dp/9652295213](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9652295213)

https://www.gefenpublishing.com/product.asp?productid=788

I do not own these volumes, so I really couldn't tell you anything about them (the translation, the author's background, etc.) but it was all I could scrounge up.

In all honesty, it's quite strange to have a translation of a translation...

Comment: The two links are to the same translation. Here's a bit about it: http://seforim.blogspot.com/2006/01/onkelos-translation.html?m=1

Comment: @Oliver - I know it's the same. I just am giving the OP variety in choosing where he/she wants to purchase from. I actually find it quite strange to have a translation of a translation... Thanks for the link.

Comment: I just received this as a gift and it looks to be excellent.  It includes the Aramaic and an English translation; the latter appears to be carefully done (I am not fluent in Aramaic and am judging by the notes) and gives a sense of where Onkeles's version differs from the original Hebrew.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Thanks for the feedback, Monica!

Comment: There are at least two important reasons to translate Targum into the current vernacular. 1. There are many times Targum is not a straight translation, but rather an explanation. 2. Targum is the most accessible popularly studied works in Aramaic. Becoming fluent in Aramaic will help with Talmudic study.

Answer (score 4):

artscroll ([here](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/ONK.html)) has started a 5-volume translation and elucidation of Targum Onkelos into English. They have published [Bereishit](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422622155.html), [Shemot](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422622582.html), [Vayikra](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422623084.html) and [Bamidbar](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422623091.html) and aim to publish [Devarim](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422623107.html) in September 2020.